# Why can't I compute a constant annotation parameter?

Tags: java, annotations

Why does the following code compile:

```
final String name = "works";
@Provides @Named(name) String provideAboutTitle() {
   return "ABC";
}
```

But the following code fails (at least with Eclipse's compiler):

```
final String name = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
@Provides @Named(name) String provideAboutTitle() {
   return "ABC";
}
```

Eclipse's compiler returns the following error:

`The value for annotation attribute Named.value must be a constant expression`

Comment: The second example is not a constant???

Comment: See also here for possible solutions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253624/how-to-supply-enum-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-in-java

Answer (score 4):

The constant expression Eclipse demands in the error message is a compile-time constant expression (not just a final variable) and the method call `UUID.randomUUID().toString();` needs to be evaluated at run-time.

While you can [write dynamic annotation values using JavaAssist at runtime](http://ayoubelabbassi.blogspot.ch/2011/01/how-to-add-annotations-at-runtime-to.html), you will lose "easy to read" feature of the annotations.

Comment: see also here for possible solutions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253624/how-to-supply-enum-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-in-java