# enum value used in annotation where a string is expected

Tags: java, enums, annotations

Suppose that I have a simple annotation:

```
 @MyAnnotation(value=<SomeString>)
```

and an enum:

```
 enum Days {
      MONDAY...
 }
```

I cant use this annotation like this:

```
 @MyAnnotation(value=Days.MONDAY.name())
 private class SomeClass {
       //some code
 }
```

This code will fail saying that "it must be a compiled time constant". I do understand why this happens and I am aware of the JSL part about compiled time constants.

My question is **why and what is the reasoning behind** not making an enum a compiled time constant according to the specification. It's not like you can change that enum name...

**EDIT for Kumar**

```
private static final class Test {

    public static final String complete = "start" + "finish";

}
```

Comment: The compiler cannot simply execute the name() method to know the value

Comment: What is your edit intending to show?  `complete` is not a compile-time constant and as such cannot be used with annotation values.

Comment: @LukeWoodward you're right, wrong copy paste, my bad. I'm trying to show that you can still perform some computation

Comment: @Eugene The above String variable "complete" is indeed compile time constant but You can use the variable value directly as compile time constant but not through a funtion even if it is a final method.In the above example,if I define a final method which returns the value of complete variable,then that method cannot act as a compile time constant.For enums,you would need to access the name variable directly and not name() method.I hope I am clear

Comment: @LukeWoodward complete is compile time constant..

Comment: @KumarAbhinav I understand that and I know that it works like that - *no problem here*. What I do want to know is why there wasn't a part in the specification about enums in compile time constants.

Comment: @Eugene Not just enums,it will not work for Strings also if you try to access a final String through a method

Comment: @KumarAbhinav yup, but enums are the obvious choice, cause they can't change. It probably has to do with the fact that the JVM compiles an enum to a class and method dispatching can't be computed to a compile time constant...

Comment: @Eugene  "Method dispatching can't be computed to a compile time constant"..true

Comment: @KumarAbhinav: it wasn't when I wrote that comment.  See the edit history.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile time constants and variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082971/compile-time-constants-and-variables)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to supply Enum value to an annotation from a Constant in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253624/how-to-supply-enum-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Method dispatching cannot be computed to a compile time constant
```

For above example,I am giving an example as **case in switch statements also require compile time constant**

```
public class Joshua{

    public final String complete = "start" + "finish";


    public void check(String argument) {


        switch(argument)
        {
         case complete: //This compiles properly
        }

        switch(argument)
        {
         case name(): //This doesn't compile
        }
    }

    public final String name(){

        return complete;
    }

}
```

With final variables you know it is a compile time constant but methods are free to return anything(a final method simply cannot be overriden)

Comment: check my edit, it has nothing to do with "some computation". Also read the JLS part about compile time constants.

Comment: I'm accepting and upvoting for your time, but this is, well, not what I expected.. Thx anyways.

Comment: @Eugene I was unable to phrase the sentence"Method dispatching cannot be computed to a compile time constant".So u deserve it

Comment: @Eugene I think u shud see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082971/compile-time-constants-and-variables

Comment: @Eugene it is simply a case of it being a fixed constant but not falling under the definiton of "compile time constant"