# Assign an enum element to an annotation

Tags: java, enums, attributes, annotations

I would like to use an enum element as a value of an annotation attribute (which requires a string value). Hence, I have created an interface holding the String constants:

```
public interface MyStringConstants {

public static final String COMPANY_LOGIN = "Company Login";
public static final String COMPANY_LOGOUT = "Company Logout";
...
}
```

Furthermore I created the enum:

```
public enum MyEnumType implements MyStringConstants {

COMPANY_CONFIGURATION_READ(MyStringConstants.COMPANY_CONFIGURATION_READ), 
COMPANY_CONFIGURATION_WRITE(MyStringConstants.COMPANY_CONFIGURATION_WRITE), 
...; 

private final String value;

private MyEnumType(final String myStringConstant) {
    this.value = myStringConstant;
}

public String getValue() {
    return this.value.toString();
}

public static MyEnumType getByValue(final String value){
    for(final MyEnumType type : values()){
        if( type.getValue().equals(value)){
            return type;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

There exists an annotation:

```
 @DeviceValidatorOperation(operationType=MyStringConstants.COMPANY_CONFIGURATION_READ)
```

I would like to define the enum as mentioned above to put as a value for the annotation's operationType attribute. Using my enum from above results in this way:

```
@DeviceValidatorOperation(operationType=MyEnumType.COMPANY_CONFIGURATION_READ.getValue())
```

results in Eclipse complaining:

```
The value for annotation attribute DeviceValidatorOperation.operationType must be a constant expression
```

How can I achieve to use an enum element as a value for an annotation's attribute?

Comment: You have to use the EnumType as `operationType` not the value of it.

Comment: Annotations are baked in at compile time, hence why you can only use constants, you could pass string in instead MyStringConstants.COMPANY_CONFIGURATION_READ

Comment: what is the type of `operationType`?

Comment: operationType is of type String.

Comment: I can't use the MyEnumType itself as value for operationType because it is defined as String (not as MyEnumType).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to supply Enum value to an annotation from a Constant in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253624/how-to-supply-enum-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-in-java)