# Using Enum constant in request header spring boot

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring boot application and want to use an Enum constant to specify the value as shown below, however, the compiler generates an error 
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Constants to String"
Here is the code block

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST, value="/user")
public User createUser(@RequestBody User user,
        @RequestHeader(value= Constants.HEADER_USER_AGENT) String userAgent
)
```

I know I can use public static String instead of Enum, but I wonder if it is possible to use Enum constants?

Comment: This is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253624/how-to-supply-enum-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-in-java

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
Constants.HEADER_USER_AGENT.toString()
```

For example? Keep in mind: an enum is **not** a string, but can be converted into one!

Comment: tried that too, i was getting "The value for annotation attribute RequestHeader.value must be a constant expression" compiler error

Answer (score 0):

For example, in your controller.

```java
@GetMapping
public void myEndpoint(@RequestHeader("X-My-Header") EMyEnum myEnum) {
    // ...
}
```

Example of header request:

```
X-My-Header: MY_ENUM_VALUE
```